# Qt-GUI Testing with Squish or other stuff

Tags: qt, testing, qpixmap, squish

Is there a way to find out the filename of a QPixmap? My intention was to test which pixmap is currently set.
I've tried Squish to find out any properties, but I've get only access to some stuff like width, height etc

Comment: I don’t think so; once loaded, a QPixmap is a in-memory representation that has no relation to the original image file location anymore.

Comment: Okay I've feared this answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that while you writing a test you already know which image you want to see. You can convert `QPixmap` to `QImage` and check if it contains the same image as expected:

```
bool same = QImage(filename) == pixmap.toImage();
```

It's not efficient but should be ok for testing purposes.